# Tabla collapsive multicolumna

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Buenos días saben como hacer una tabla collapsive multicolumna como esta?, o algun plugin que haga ese trabajo:

Una empresa tiene varios departamentos, entonces el row de empresa tiene q ser collapsive, ahora a su ves los departamentos tienen varias áreas, así que los departamentos tienen que ser collapsives, y los demás datos que se muestran a según se va a haciendo el filtrado me dejo entender?, dejo una imagen para reverenciar.

Ojo no agruparlo todo en una sola coolumna, osea cada columna de por si debe tener su símbolo (+ O - ) ¿Me dejo entender?

[image: ESTA tabla]

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías añadir más información a la Pregunta? _"Qué has intentado"_, como, código de ejemplo.  De esta manera se te podrá brindar una mejor respuesta. Tal como esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones, por lo cual son bienvenidas en la sala de [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).